# Make bootstrap navbar divider evenly spaced

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do we make the vertical dividers in the navigation bar evenly spaced out?

Here's the HTML and CSS i'm currently using.

HTML:

```
<li class="divider-vertical"><a href = "#">Contact Us</a></li>
```

CSS:

```
.divider-vertical {
height: 50px;
margin: 0 9px;
border-left: 1px solid #F2F2F2;
border-right: 1px solid #FFF;
}
```

Navbar code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
       <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
       </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href = "#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="divider-vertical"><a href = "#">About</a></li>
            <li class="divider-vertical"><a href = "#">Jobs</a></li>
            <li class="divider-vertical"><a href = "#">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li class="divider-vertical"><a href = "#">Resources</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: What do you mean?  What exactly are you looking for?  If you set the height of each divider then it will be evenly spaced in accordance to the height you set

Comment: Hi I would like to have the output like this:---->  Home | About | Contact  <----but the output is currently like this: ---> Home | *two tab space* About          *two tab space* |  Contact  <---

Comment: Can you post your entire navbar code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve the effect you are after. 
Here is a quick fix that will solve your issue and give you the result you need.

```
 .divider-vertical {
height: 50px;
margin: 0 0 0 9px;
padding: 0 0 0 9px;
border-left: 1px solid red;
}
```

A better approach which would save you a little html writing would be to do something like the following:

1. Remove your `.divider-vertical` class from the HTML
2. Style your `.li` elements, use `margin` and `padding` on the same side as your `border` - in this case the right
3. we will use Pseudo class `:last-child` to remove some css attributes from the last menu item

```css
li {
  border-right: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 9px 0 0;
  padding: 0 9px 0 0;
}

li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
       <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
       </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href = "#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#">Jobs</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#">Resources</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this.  I added the `divider-vertical` class to the `Home` `<li>` tag to give it styling.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x4bwyn9b/1/)

HTML

```
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="divider-vertical"><a href = "#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="divider-vertical"><a href = "#">About</a></li>
        <li class="divider-vertical"><a href = "#">Jobs</a></li>
        <li class="divider-vertical"><a href = "#">Resources</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
.divider-vertical {
    height: 50px;
    width:100px;
    margin: auto;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid red;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your CSS to the following:

```
.divider-vertical {
    height: 50px;
    border-left: 1px solid #F2F2F2;
    border-right: 1px solid #FFF;
}
```

You had margin on the left and right set to 9px.

If you want the extra space use:

```
padding: 0 9px;
```

instead. [here](http://jsfiddle.net/s403nnLL) is a working example, but you will need to stretch the panel with the result to see it since bootstrap is making your nav into a navicon at jsfiddle's default width.